# open .data file using tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision

I have recently started machine learning using python and tensorflow and i have found many free online datasets to play with.One of them is uci machine learning datasets ([dermatology dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/dermatology)) but it has only got a .data file can someone link code snippets to make it work on a given image to identify the diseases

Comment: the file is a `csv` file. can you show us what you already have done so we can help you better ?

Answer (score 0):

As @zython mentioned, the file is just a CSV, you will find a ton of examples with a simple search. Here is one https://learningtensorflow.com/ReadingFilesBasic/